# Ruckus ZoneDIrector frequently issues new IP addresses

Tags: wireless, dhcp

We have a ZoneDirector 1100 appliance with 8 access points. Our software engineers are accessing the network via DHCP-provisioned IP addresses. Normally, whatever IP they land on is irrelevant to their day to day activities. But we now have a team currently working on a project that requires a reasonably consistent IP. I set the DHCP lease time to 'two weeks', yet we're seeing IP's being renewed more on the scale of hours, if not minutes.

Can anyone make a reasonable guess as to what is causing this?

We are on the latest firmware, and I searched through the support site to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried packet tracing the DHCP traffic for those clients that are renewing too often?

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other devices on the network that would be handing out DHCP on the same IP table? A router, a DHCP server? I've already had clients hook up a residential grade router on the network and it confused the heck out of me for a couple days.

Comment: Actually, there are a couple of test networks that are not under IT control... sitting directly behind the questionable zone. We've mentioned this in the past, but they are doing essential work. However, they are not using the same address space as the corporate network. I believe that this may be down to wi-fi interference and nothing more.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although it doesn't answer the specific question of "Why is this happening?", the best answer I could give you is: **Don't use the Zone Director for DHCP.**

Per Ruckus Wireless themselves in the [Zone Director User Guide](https://support.ruckuswireless.com/documents/223-zonedirector-release-9-5-user-guide/download) under the "Enabling the Built-in DHCP Server" section:

> NOTE: Ruckus Wireless recommends that you only enable the built-in DHCP server if there are 
>   no other DHCP servers on the network

So it appears **they** don't even recommend using it for DHCP; probably because of odd behavior such as you are seeing.

At the very least, it is an extremely limited feature-set.  Most work-arounds for your problem would be to configure the trouble clients with statically configured IP addresses/fixed leases in the DHCP server.  However there is no capability for that in the Zone Director 1100.

The best way around your problem at this point, would be to configure the Zone Director for DHCP Relay.    Once the Zone Director forwards the DHCP requests to an actual DHCP server, you would have much greater control over the DHCP process.

Comment: Nice answer. I will take this under consideration, and begin a discussion. It seems like a good work-around.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely client related as a DHCP server does not renew an address unless requested by the client.  Princeton has some interesting posts on iOS bugs that may be related.

http://www.net.princeton.edu/apple-ios/ios40-requests-DHCP-too-often.html

Comment: The device in question is a Blackberry Z10, though I've seen similar issues with Android devices. Curiously, my iPhone does not exhibit this problem at all and retains the same IP for weeks.